# Apps Script for the Google Sheets/Slides. Each row should be converted to a discrete Slide

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

Basically I have this script written to turn each row of Sheets into a discrete Slide. But, every time I run the script, duplicate slides get created. This would be a Sheet/Slide Deck that get new information added every week and I don't want to have to delete the slides already present just to run the script again. Because there will be information added to the Slides once they are created.

I have made the script and run it however the duplicates are killing me and can't seem to find the fix. Perhaps the whole script is wrong.

```
function createOneSlidePerRow() {

  // Replace <INSERT_SLIDE_DECK_ID> wih the ID of your 
  // Google Slides presentation.
  let masterDeckID = "insert-id";

  // Open the presentation and get the slides in it.
  let deck = SlidesApp.openById(masterDeckID);
  let slides = deck.getSlides();

  // The 2nd slide is the template that will be duplicated
  // once per row in the spreadsheet.
  let masterSlide = slides[1];

  // Load data from the spreadsheet.
  let dataRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getDataRange();
  let sheetContents = dataRange.getValues();

  // Save the header in a variable called header
  let header = sheetContents.shift();

  // Create an array to save the data to be written back to the sheet.
  // We'll use this array to save links to the slides that are created.
  let updatedContents = [];

  // Reverse the order of rows because new slides will
  // be inserted at the top. Without this, the order of slides
  // will be the inverse of the ordering of rows in the sheet. 
  sheetContents.reverse();

  // For every row, create a new slide by duplicating the master slide
  // and replace the template variables with data from that row.
  sheetContents.forEach(function (row) {

    // Insert a new slide by duplicating the master slide.
    let slide = masterSlide.duplicate();

    // Populate data in the slide that was created
    slide.replaceAllText("{{name}}", row[0]);
    slide.replaceAllText("{{school}}", row[1]);
    slide.replaceAllText("{{hometown}}", row[2])
    slide.replaceAllText("{{Test 1}}", row[3])
    slide.replaceAllText("{{Test 2}}", row[4])
    slide.replaceAllText("{{Interview}}", row[16])
    slide.replaceAllText("{{Overall}}", row [17])
  

    // Create the URL for the slide using the deck's ID and the ID
    // of the slide.
    let slideUrl = `https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/${deck.getId()}/edit#slide=id.${slide.getObjectId()}`;

    // Add this URL to the 5th column of the row and add this row
    // to the data to be written back to the sheet.
    row[18] = slideUrl;
    updatedContents.push(row);
  });

  // Add the header back (remember it was removed using 
  // sheetContents.shift())
  updatedContents.push(header);

  // Reverse the array to preserve the original ordering of 
  // rows in the sheet.
  updatedContents.reverse();

  // Write the updated data back to the Google Sheets spreadsheet.
  dataRange.setValues(updatedContents);


}
```

Comment: Where in the script are you tracking if you've already created a slide for a particular row of data?

Comment: Can I ask what kind of data are you converting to slides where each row goes to a slide?

Comment: https://imgur.com/TUPjgii